# Rails 4 - link_to helper - path to associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path, link-to

I am trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I'm still getting confused with basic concepts.

I'm trying to put a link on my profile show page, to the name of the associated organisations.

I have a profile model and an organisation model.

The associations are: profile belongs to organisation and organisation has_many profiles.

On my profile show page, I have tried every different way I can think of to try and make a link to the organisation show page for the associated organisation. I have tried:

```
<%= link_to @profile.organisation.try(:title).upcase, profile_organisation_path(organisation.id) %>

<%= link_to @profile.organisation.try(:title).upcase, profile_organisation_path(organisation_id) %>

<%= link_to @profile.organisation.try(:title).upcase, organisation_path(profile.organisation) %>
```

I have tried about 20 variations on this. I don't know what I'm doing and I don't understand how to read the API docs. So I'm stuck.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Comment: Two things: I need to see your controller (as this is how we tell the view which organisation we're talking about).  It would also be very helpful to know what error you're getting.  My suspicion is that your organisation variables are empty but I can't tell based on what you've given.

Comment: the profile controller or the organisation controller?

Comment: I know the variable is working because when I just populate the organisation title (not as a link), it gives me the organisation title (stored in the org table).

Comment: I'd be interested in your profile controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<%= link_to @profile.organisation.try(:title).upcase, organisation_path(@profile.organisation.id) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller aside, I think I see what's going on.  Try making the following edits

```
<%= link_to @profile.organisation.try(:title).upcase, organisation_path(@profile.organisation) %>
```

Unless you somehow set the local variable organisation elsewhere, you need to use your instance variable to specify the associated organisation, just like you did in naming the link.

Comment: undefined method `profile_organisation_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ff3ed37b9f8>:0x007ff409ba4ca8>

Comment: I think Matt's answer has it.